# ld cannot find library that exists

Tags: c++, cmake, ld

I'm trying to link my code to a library called clik. I'm passing the directory to ld with -L *DIRECTORY* and -lclik. *DIRECTORY* contains the file libclik.so. However, ld gives and error "ld: cannot find -lclik". Any ideas what could cause this?

To be more specific, I am using cmake. In cmake I have something like

```
find_library(CLIKLIB clik DIRECTORY)
```

and then for my executable I do:

```
target_link_libraries(executable ${CLIKLIB})
```

and that's how cmake generates the code for linking to clik but then ld fails.

Comment: Can't obviously replicate your problem exactly, but have you tried doing
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CLIK_LIBRARY_DIR})

Comment: Are you sure that library you want to link with is *compatible* with running OS? `find_library` just search files(content has no meaning for it), but linker can silently ignore incompatible libraries. For check compatibility you can compile simple program directly using `gcc` and passing appropriate flags to linker.

Comment: I don't understand what the DIRECTORY part of find_library(CLIKLIB clik DIRECTORY) is supposed to be doing, can you explain that? It's not a CMake directive ( as far as I know ). If it's supposed to contain your path, as you sort of suggest above, then your syntax is incorrect. You would want find_library(CLIKLIB clik PATHS ${DIRECTORY}). You might want to try message("CLIKLIB: "${CLIKLIB}) to make sure it's set how you think.

Comment: The library is compiled on the same OS. The DIRECTORY is not a variable, I just replace it by the actual path. After that `message("CLIKLIB: ${CLIKLIB}")` shows the correct library. One solution I found was to add `-dynamic` to the linker flags, and then it links just fine. I was hoping to find a better solution though where cmake takes care of these things (as it should), such as linking the shared library with the appropriate flags, so that I don't have to manually add flags.